Celery + Redis weird connection error with task that takes 5 minutes?
I've been trying to debug this weird error where a task fails on the celery worker if the task takes over like 5m. It also doesn't show a useful error, just this:
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 520, in trace_task
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    task.backend.mark_as_done(
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 157, in mark_as_done
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 526, in store_result
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 981, in _store_result
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self._set_with_state(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta), state)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 854, in _set_with_state
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return self.set(key, value)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 400, in set
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return self.ensure(self._set, (key, value), **retry_policy)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 384, in ensure
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return retry_over_time(
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 409, in _set
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    pipe.execute()
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1530, in execute
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 62, in call_with_retry
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return do()
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1531, in <lambda>
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    lambda: execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error),
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1416, in _execute_transaction
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.raise_first_error(commands, response)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1451, in raise_first_error
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    raise r
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1385, in _execute_transaction
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.parse_response(connection, "_")
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1462, in parse_response
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    result = Redis.parse_response(self, connection, command_name, **options)
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 584, in parse_response
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    response = connection.read_response()
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 616, in read_response
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    raise response
2024-11-14T07:25:40Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  warn(RuntimeWarning(
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1794, in safe_apply_callback
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    fun(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py", line 624, in on_failure
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.task.backend.mark_as_failure(
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 167, in mark_as_failure
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.store_result(task_id, exc, state,
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 526, in store_result
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 981, in _store_result
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self._set_with_state(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta), state)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 854, in _set_with_state
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return self.set(key, value)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 400, in set
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return self.ensure(self._set, (key, value), **retry_policy)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 384, in ensure
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return retry_over_time(
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 409, in _set
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    pipe.execute()
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1530, in execute
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 62, in call_with_retry
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    return do()
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]           ^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1531, in <lambda>
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    lambda: execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error),
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1416, in _execute_transaction
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.raise_first_error(commands, response)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1451, in raise_first_error
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    raise r
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1385, in _execute_transaction
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    self.parse_response(connection, "_")
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1462, in parse_response
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    result = Redis.parse_response(self, connection, command_name, **options)
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 584, in parse_response
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    response = connection.read_response()
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 616, in read_response
2024-11-14T07:25:41Z app[48e501ec74e118] den [info]    raise response

Here is the task:
@tracer.start_as_current_span("transcribe_runpod")
def transcribe_runpod(audio_url: str, primary_language: str) -> dict[str, str]:
    log.info(f"Transcribing audio from {audio_url} with primary language {primary_language}")

    response = whisper_endpoint.run_sync({
        "input": {
            "model": "large-v2",
            "audio": audio_url,
            "word_timestamps": True,
            "language": language,
            "logprob_threshold": None,
            "no_speech_threshold": None,
            "condition_on_previous_text": True,
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "initial_prompt": transliterated_words,
        }
    })

    if not response or "transcription" not in response or "word_timestamps" not in response:
        raise RunpodResponseEmptyError()

    log.info("Transcribed audio", response=response)
    return response["transcription"], response["word_timestamps"]

which is called by
@celery.task(bind=True)
def transcribe_runpod_task(self, audio_url: str, primary_language: str):
    return transcribe_runpod(audio_url, primary_language)

Now, shorter audio files work great, something about this larger file is causing what looks like a timeout.
This issue shows up on celery[redis] 5.4.0, as well as 5.5.0rc1. I'm wondering if there is some sort of configuration I'm missing?

The traceback is cut off.   What's the error?

that is the traceback. it's cut off for me in the response as well

You're facing a timeout issue when running a long duration celery task approximately 5 minutes or longer with a redis backend. The redis backend seems to fail to store results due to connection timeouts or limitations in handling long task durations.
To address this issue, you can define a reusable base celery task class with robust retry logic and then use that in your task definition. You can do someting following
First, create a base class that handles retries and includes hooks for logging on success, failure, and retry attempts:
from celery import Task
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class BaseTaskWithRetry(Task):
    autoretry_for = (Exception,)
    retry_backoff = True
    retry_backoff_max = 60
    retry_jitter = True
    acks_late = True

    def on_retry(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo=None):
        log.warning(f"Retrying task {task_id} due to {exc}. Args: {args}, Kwargs: {kwargs}")
        super().on_retry(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo=None):
        log.error(f"Task {task_id} failed due to {exc}. Args: {args}, Kwargs: {kwargs}", exc_info=True)
        super().on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        log.info(f"Task {task_id} succeeded. Return value: {retval}. Args: {args}, Kwargs: {kwargs}")
        super().on_success(retval, task_id, args, kwargs)

Now, use the BaseTaskWithRetry class to define your celery task:
from celery import shared_task
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@shared_task(bind=True, base=BaseTaskWithRetry, soft_time_limit=1800, time_limit=1850)
def transcribe_runpod_task(self, audio_url: str, primary_language: str):
    """
    Celery task to transcribe audio using Runpod.
    Automatically retries on failure.
    """
    log.info(f"Starting transcription for {audio_url} with language {primary_language}")
    try:
        # call the transcription function
        response = transcribe_runpod(audio_url, primary_language)
        return response
    except Exception as exc:
        log.error(f"Transcription failed: {exc}", exc_info=True)
        # the retry will automatically call the `on_retry` method
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)

To trigger the task, you can use the following code:
transcribe_runpod_task.apply_async(
    args=["https://example.com/audio.mp3", "en"],
    countdown=20
)

